# Android Design cancel effect of a widget to center alignment

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout, padding

I am designing an interface and I have two textview and I want to align second text to center. It is like that (red line is center of layout):

[image]

I want like that :

[image]

I mean I want to cancel effect of first textview. **I can do it with PADDING but I don't know if padding is ok for different resolutions.** Do you recommend something else?

XML:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewLife"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:text="00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="150dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

using relative layout it can be fixed. and better use sp for fontsize.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewLife"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="150sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextViewLife"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/TextViewLife"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="50sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: y u cant use relative layout?

Comment: u should use relative layout cos by using linear layout u should give weight proerty but it results nested weight.. so its better to use relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout. Than set android:layout_centerInParent for id/TextViewLife and attach TextView01 to the TextViewLife (example - android:layout_leftOf="@+id/TextViewLife")

P.S. RelativeLayoutDocumentation - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html